# Is this a strict aliasing violation?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

```
struct __packed element {
    char val;
};

void foo(struct element arr[4], uint32_t a) {
    uint32_t* i = (uint32_t*)arr;
    *i = a;
}

int main(void) {
    struct element arr[4] __aligned(4);

    foo(arr, 5);
    ...
}
```

Pretty much as the title, is this a strict aliasing violation in C?

Assuming that arr's stored type is `struct element[4]`

Comment: You can use a character type to point to any other type, not the other way around, AFAIR.

Comment: your cast is broken so whatever you have UB.

Comment: `__packed` already takes you outside of the  C Standard

Comment: The question would be improved by showing the code that calls `foo`, including how the space being written was allocated

Comment: @M.M OK 1 second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this (`*i = a`) is a strict aliasing violation.

N1570 §6.5 p7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types: 88)
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>     object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>     effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>     members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

None of the above requirements are met:

- `uint32_t` is not compatible with effective type `char`.
- No qualified types of `char` used.
- `uint32_t` is not unsigned version of `char`.
- `struct element` has no `uint32_t` members.
- `uint32_t` is not a character type.

It would be legal if effective type of the original array would be `uint32_t` or it would be allocated with `malloc` for which effective type takes place at the assignment.

```
uint32_t arr;
foo((struct element*)&arr, 5); // Possible pointer conversion issues still apply
```

or

```
void * arr = malloc(4);
foo(arr, 5);
```

---

Note that `uint32_t* i = (uint32_t*)arr` might also lead to *undefined behaviour*, if converted address cannot be stored in `uint32_t*` type variable. But that is *implementation specific*, and thus depends on your platform.

Comment: How can you unconditionally state it's UB, when the OP has only shown code that writes to `arr`? If properly aligned and sized you can store anything there, if you always read it using the same type as used for the write.

Comment: This might be one for another question, but could you shoot me a link where I can read up on the point you made in your last paragraph? I was under the impression that all pointers are the same size (except function pointers). ty.

Comment: @n.m. Al yes, please assume that arr's stored type is a `struct element[]` I will update my question with this

Comment: @jayjay [6.3.2.3 p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): *"A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. ..."*

Comment: @alain Reading should be irrelevant, but you are right that there is possibility for it to work if original array would have been allocated with `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you will read `element arr[4]`, and on how `arr` was allocated.

If you will read it as

```
uint32_t value = *(uint32_t*)arr;
```

and `arr` was either allocated dynamically (using `malloc`), or allocated as an `int32_t` object with automatic storage duration ("on the stack"),
it's OK.
If this is the case, your write changes the effective type to `int32_t`.
But if you want to read using a type unrelated to `uint32_t`, and not a character type, it's undefined behavior.

Also, `arr` needs to be properly aligned for `int32_t`. (If it was obtained using `malloc`, it automatically is.)

---

After the question was edited, it becomes clear that it is indeed undefined behavior, because `arr` is allocated as follows:

```
struct element arr[4] __aligned(4);
```

Comment: Why @n.m.? If properly aligned and sized, you can reuse the memory and store `int32_t` if you read it as `int32_t`, no?

Comment: Sorry didn't see that the function stores.

Comment: I missed it at first too :)

Comment: The space pointed to by `arr` has to either be part of a dynamically allocated block, or have been declared as `uint32_t` (or `int32_t`) in the first place.  The *effective type* of declared variables is always their declared type; it's only malloc'd space whose effective type can change by writing to it

Comment: Thanks @M.M, I wasn't sure about that. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Does a write not count as "access"?

Comment: Oh I see where you're coming from, sorry I spoiled you answer with an edit. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: No problem, I added a line.